# Right place to store the int ID value ,if an application crashes or restarts in c# windows application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I am  reading the last updated integer application id value from  settings file when application crashes or restarts happens in c# windows application.
But i would like to know whether this approch is good or not ?
Also please let me know is there any other option for storing the variables during application crash or restart.

Comment: what makes you concerned about using a settings file?

Comment: In the last place I worked at, they wanted us to store such information in the registry.

Comment: @arao6:If we use the registry key.In this case , is it good to update a new value of ID everytime to Registry.?

Comment: @Jonesy:When my application crashes or restarts i want to get the last ID value,so i am storing this in settings files for every new ID value.I dont want to use any database for a single value storage.Please let me know is it good to update a settings file for every new value of ID .

Comment: That depends on your specific use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This entirely depends on how much trouble you'll get into when you re-use an ID and how easily you can recover from that.  And keep in mind that it is not just limited to program crashes, you'll have the same problem when somebody trips over the power cord or a machine's hard drive fails and needs to be replaced.  Which significantly cuts down on the number of "good" places to store this info.  It is usually a lot of trouble, always consider providing the user with a way to recover.  A settings file is not easy to find, you need to help.

The standard guidance is to store it in the same place as the data that depends on the ID value.  So you'll lose them at the same time.  And get them backed up at the same time :)  Always favor a database table's identity column for example.

And **very** strongly consider using a Guid so you never care about the previous value.

Comment: :Thanks for response.Yes, you are correct .if we can use database table it will be good .But for my application  for single value updationi dont want to go for database.Please suggest anyother alternative ways?

Comment: Asked and answered.  Store it in the same place as the data that depends on it so you'll lose them at the same time.  So if is a file stored on the local drive then the registry is a decent place for example.  A setting is okayish, as long as you save them right away so you minimize the risk.  If it is stored on another machine that multiple clients can get to then you'll have a much bigger problem and you really do need a Guid.  Your requirements are otherwise too vague to stick a fork into it, you are not specific enough about the kind of trouble you'll run into when an ID is reused.